# How to change Codename One Chart background color

Tags: codenameone

am trying to change the background of Chart Renderer but it's not working for all the chart types I have.

used this code

```
renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
renderer.setBackgroundColor(GlobalVal.CHART_BG_COLOR);
```

and it worked for DoughnutChart but did not work for BarChart & CubicLineChart, shows black.

Is there any other method I should call?

Comment: Did you use `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer` or some other renderer?

Comment: Yes, I used XYMultipleSeriesRenderer for BarChart and CubicLineChart but used DefaultRenderer for DoughnutChart following the examples from the demo.

Answer (score 2):

You can try putting it into its own container and style the container with a UIID. Chart styling seems pretty tricky.

Comment: I customized the ChartComponent like:

Comment: ChartCompnent c = new ChartComponent(chart); c.setUIID("Container"); and Container uiid has transparent background. With this the area in which bars are drawn(for the BarChart) is affected as expected by taking the background color of the containing container for ChartComponent, but the surrounding area is black.

Answer (score 2):

Have figured it out 
`renderer.setMarginsColor(GlobalVal.CHART_BG_COLOR);`
did the job.